# Using python to get images from an mp3 file

Tags: python, image, mp3

I found that this command using eyed3 works fine on my mp3 file writing the images found to the directory DIR

```
eyeD3 --write-images=DIR  file.mp3
```

But I would like to use this in a python program could someone give me an example
on how to do that.

This snippet works fine

```
audiofile = eyed3.load("file.mp3")
        print(audiofile.tag.album)
        print(audiofile.tag.artist) 
        print(audiofile.tag.title)  
        print(audiofile.tag.track_num)
```

Answer (score 4):

This oughta do it.
I've added the image type as well, as there can be multiple images in a single MP3 file, and you didn't specify which one you needed. For most files this would be the album cover.

```
import eyed3

audio_file = eyed3.load("test.mp3")
album_name = audio_file.tag.album
artist_name = audio_file.tag.artist
for image in audio_file.tag.images:
    image_file = open("{0} - {1}({2}).jpg".format(artist_name, album_name, image.picture_type), "wb")
    print("Writing image file: {0} - {1}({2}).jpg".format(artist_name, album_name, image.picture_type))
    image_file.write(image.image_data)
    image_file.close()
```

Comment: Hi SteveMany thanks for that which worked perfectly I am very new to this so

Comment: -can you tell me how to extract the actual .jpg reference so I can display it in my gui - many thanks! Terry

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Had it really busy lately. 
You should be able to use the image.image_data as a reference

Comment: Hi Thanks for that information but I still have a problem as I want to load the image directly into a Qlabel using  QPixmap. This works if I write the file as you suggested above and read it back in with image = QPixmap(fileName) and then  use setPixmap.  But I am sure there is a more elegant way to do that? Many thanks for any further help

Comment: @profTC `label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(QImage.fromData( image.image_data)))`.